# Not able to get playlist tracks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spotify

There are few playlists in my account e.g "Discover Weekly" or "Bollywood Top 50" which are provided by the Spotify but I'm unable to fetch its tracks using this https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks API call.

But If I create a playlist manually then I'll be able to fetch its tracks. I'm not sure about this awkward behavior.

Please help me out to resolve it.

Comment: i am also phasing these kind of error in **android**  from using [https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks]   getting error 401: authentication error ..so how to solve these please suggest anyone if done....!!!

Answer (score 0):

I find that the most common reason to why this request fails is that the request is made with the wrong `{user_id}` - it needs to be the playlist's *owner's* username, **not** the username of the user for whom you're retrieve playlists.

If this isn't the case, please provide the error message you're getting back from the Web API.

Read more about [Get a Playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlist/).